# Simultaneous Threads in C++ using <thread>

Tags: c++, multithreading, simultaneous

I have been looking around and I am not sure why is this happening. I've seen lots of Tuts related to using threads on Linux but not much on what I am sharing right now.

Code:

```
int j = 0;
while(j <= 10)
{
    myThreads[j] = std::thread(task, j);
    myThreads[j].join();
    j+=1;
}
```

So I am simply trying to create 10 threads and execute them all.
The task is pretty simple and it's been dealt with pretty well but the problem is that not the whole threads are being executed.

***It's executing only 1 thread and it's waiting for it to finish then executing the other one etc...***

PS: I know that the main function will quit after activating those threads but I read about this and I am sure I can fix it in many ways.

So I want to execute all those threads simultaneously.

Thanks a lot in advance,
MarioAda.

Comment: You are repeatedly starting one and then waiting for it to finish (join). How do you expect that to run more than just the two threads in parallel?

Comment: sidenote: you are actually creating 11 threads 0..10

Comment: Make it 12, as every process has at least one thread. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are starting threads and then joining them right away.
You need to create, do your work and only then join in some other loop.
Besides, you generally put the threads in a vector so you can reference/join them (which you seem to be doing, although in an array, since this is tagged C++, I encourage you to use a `std::vector` instead).

The strategy is the same as with `pthreads` before it: your declare an array of threads, push them to run, and then join.

The code below is from [here](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/03/cpp11-concurrency-part1-start-threads.html).

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void hello(){
    std::cout << "Hello from thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        threads.push_back(std::thread(hello));
    }

    for(auto& thread : threads){
        thread.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its been some time and I forgot to thank you. Anyways, here it is, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There's a bit more advanced technique for making such threads run even more simultaneously.

The problem with the naive approach is, the threads created in the beginning have too much time to run their functions before the last threads are even created. So, when the last threads are just created, the first ones have already executed significant parts of their functions.

In order to avoid that, we can use a counter (protected by a mutex) and a condition variable. Each thread that has been created and is now ready to start running its internal function, will increment the counter and check if it has become equal to the total number of threads (i.e., if this thread was the last one to increment the counter). If it was, it will notify all the other threads (using the condition variable) that it's time to start. Otherwise, it will wait on the condition variable until some other thread sets the counter to their total number and notifies the remaining threads (including this one).

This way, all the threads will start (almost) simultaneously, only after each and every one of them has been created and is actually ready to execute its function.

Here is my implementation of a class `ConcurrentRunner` which does that.

First, a C++11-compliant simplified version that will be easier to understand:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

// Object that runs multiple functions, each in its own thread, starting them as simultaneously as possible.
class ConcurrentRunner final
{
public:
    template<typename... BackgroundThreadsFunctions>
    explicit ConcurrentRunner(const std::function<void()>& this_thread_function, const BackgroundThreadsFunctions&... background_threads_functions)
        : _this_thread_function{this_thread_function}
        , _num_threads_total{1 + sizeof...(BackgroundThreadsFunctions)}
    {
        this->PrepareBackgroundThreads({ background_threads_functions... });
    }

    ConcurrentRunner(const ConcurrentRunner&) = delete;
    ConcurrentRunner& operator=(const ConcurrentRunner&) = delete;

    // Executes `ThreadProc` for this thread's function and waits for all of the background threads to finish.
    void Run()
    {
        this->ThreadProc(_this_thread_function);

        for (auto& background_thread : _background_threads)
            background_thread.join();
    }

private:
    // Creates the background threads: each of them will execute `ThreadProc` with its respective function.
    void PrepareBackgroundThreads(const std::vector<std::function<void()>>& background_threads_functions)
    {
        // Iterate through the vector of the background threads' functions and create a new thread with `ThreadProc` for each of them.
        _background_threads.reserve(background_threads_functions.size());
        for (const auto& background_thread_function : background_threads_functions)
        {
            _background_threads.emplace_back([this, function = background_thread_function]()
            {
                this->ThreadProc(function);
            });
        }
    }

    // Procedure that will be executed by each thread, including the "main" thread and all background ones.
    void ThreadProc(const std::function<void()>& function)
    {
        // Increment the `_num_threads_waiting_for_start_signal` while the mutex is locked, thus signalizing that a new thread is ready to start.
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};
        ++_num_threads_waiting_for_start_signal;
        const bool ready_to_go = (_num_threads_waiting_for_start_signal == _num_threads_total);
        lock.unlock();

        if (ready_to_go)
        {
            // If this thread was the last one of the threads which must start simultaneously, notify all other threads that they are ready to start.
            _cv.notify_all();
        }
        else
        {
            // If this thread was not the last one of the threads which must start simultaneously, wait on `_cv` until all other threads are ready.
            lock.lock();
            _cv.wait(lock, [this]()
                     {
                         return (_num_threads_waiting_for_start_signal == _num_threads_total);
                     });
            lock.unlock();
        }

        // Execute this thread's internal function.
        function();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> _this_thread_function;
    std::vector<std::thread> _background_threads;

    const unsigned int _num_threads_total;
    unsigned int _num_threads_waiting_for_start_signal{0}; // counter of the threads which are ready to start running their functions
    mutable std::mutex _mutex; // mutex that protects the counter
    std::condition_variable _cv; // waited on by all threads but the last one; notified when the last thread increments the counter
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Example of usage:

#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    std::atomic<int> x{0};

    {
        ConcurrentRunner runner{[&]() { x += 1; }, [&]() { x += 10; }, [&]() { x += 100; }};
        runner.Run();
    }

    return (x.load() == 111) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

And now the same logic with more templates, less allocations, no unnecessary copies and type erasure, but somewhat harder to read (requires C++17):

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helper template `ForEachTupleElement` (meant to be in some other header file).

#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace Detail
{
    template<typename Tuple, typename Function, std::size_t... I>
    constexpr void ForEachTupleElement(Tuple&& tuple, Function function, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        int dummy[] = { 0, (((void)(function(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))))), 0)... };
        (void)dummy;
    }
}

// Applies a given function (typically - with a template operator(), e.g., a generic lambda) to each element of a tuple.
template<typename Tuple, typename Function, std::size_t... I>
constexpr void ForEachTupleElement(Tuple&& tuple, Function function)
{
    Detail::ForEachTupleElement(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), function,
                                std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>>{});
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <array>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// Common non-template part of the `ConcurrentRunner` implementation.
class ConcurrentRunnerBase
{
protected:
    inline ConcurrentRunnerBase() = default;
    inline ~ConcurrentRunnerBase() = default;

protected:
    unsigned int _num_threads_waiting_for_start_signal{0}; // protected by `mutex`
    mutable std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _cv; // waited on by all threads but the last one; notified when the last thread increments the counter
};

// Object that runs multiple functions, each in its own thread, starting them as simultaneously as possible.
template<typename ThisThreadFunction, std::size_t NumberOfBackgroundThreads>
class ConcurrentRunner final : private ConcurrentRunnerBase
{
public:
    template<typename ThisThreadFunctionArg, typename... BackgroundThreadsFunctions>
    explicit ConcurrentRunner(ThisThreadFunctionArg&& this_thread_function, BackgroundThreadsFunctions&&... background_threads_functions)
        : _this_thread_function{std::forward<ThisThreadFunctionArg>(this_thread_function)}
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(BackgroundThreadsFunctions) == NumberOfBackgroundThreads);
        this->Prepare(std::forward<BackgroundThreadsFunctions>(background_threads_functions)...);
    }

    ConcurrentRunner(const ConcurrentRunner&) = delete;
    ConcurrentRunner& operator=(const ConcurrentRunner&) = delete;

    // Executes `ThreadProc` for this thread's function and waits for all of the background threads to finish.
    void Run()
    {
        this->ThreadProc(std::move(_this_thread_function));

        for (auto& background_thread : _background_threads)
            background_thread.join();
    }

private:
    // Creates the background threads: each of them will execute `ThreadProc` with its respective function.
    template<typename... BackgroundThreadsFunctions>
    void Prepare(BackgroundThreadsFunctions&&... background_threads_functions)
    {
        // Copies of the argument functions (created by move constructors where possible), collected in a tuple.
        std::tuple<std::decay_t<BackgroundThreadsFunctions>...> background_threads_functions_tuple{
            std::forward<BackgroundThreadsFunctions>(background_threads_functions)...
        };

        // Iterate through the tuple of the background threads' functions and create a new thread with `ThreadProc` for each of them.
        unsigned int index_in_array = 0;
        ForEachTupleElement(std::move(background_threads_functions_tuple), [this, &index_in_array](auto&& function)
                            {
                                auto i = index_in_array++;
                                _background_threads[i] = std::thread{[this, function = std::move(function)]() mutable
                                {
                                    this->ThreadProc(std::move(function));
                                }};
                            });
    }

    // Procedure that will be executed by each thread, including the "main" thread and all background ones.
    template<typename Function>
    void ThreadProc(Function&& function)
    {
        // Increment the `_num_threads_waiting_for_start_signal` while the mutex is locked, thus signalizing that a new thread is ready to start.
        std::unique_lock lock{_mutex};
        ++_num_threads_waiting_for_start_signal;
        const bool ready_to_go = (_num_threads_waiting_for_start_signal == (1 + NumberOfBackgroundThreads));
        lock.unlock();

        if (ready_to_go)
        {
            // If this thread was the last one of the threads which must start simultaneously, notify all other threads that they are ready to start.
            _cv.notify_all();
        }
        else
        {
            // If this thread was not the last one of the threads which must start simultaneously, wait on `_cv` until all other threads are ready.
            lock.lock();
            _cv.wait(lock, [this]() noexcept -> bool
                     {
                         return (_num_threads_waiting_for_start_signal == (1 + NumberOfBackgroundThreads));
                     });
            lock.unlock();
        }

        // Execute this thread's internal function.
        std::forward<Function>(function)();
    }

private:
    ThisThreadFunction _this_thread_function;
    std::array<std::thread, NumberOfBackgroundThreads> _background_threads;
};

template<typename T, typename... U>
ConcurrentRunner(T&&, U&&...) -> ConcurrentRunner<std::decay_t<T>, sizeof...(U)>;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Example of usage:

#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    std::atomic<int> x{0};

    {
        ConcurrentRunner runner{[&]() { x += 1; }, [&]() { x += 10; }, [&]() { x += 100; }};
        runner.Run();
    }

    return (x.load() == 111) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because [join](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) blocks the current thread until your thread has finished.
You should only start your threads in the loop you already have, and call the join() function of the threads in a second loop.